# RDP successful but RPC server unavailable error for QWINSTA

Tags: rdp

I am using Windows 7 machine as a client. The server is a Windows Server 2008 machine.
When I access the server using Remote Desktop Application (mstsc), it is successfully connected. But when I execute the following command in command prompt, I get "RPC Server is unavailable" error.

```
qwinsta /server:servername
```

Note:
My machine and the client machine are on different domains. It is just my guess that the QWINSTA command does not use 3389 port which is default for RDP.

Please help in solving this issue.

Comment: Have you tried using the FQDN of the server?

Comment: What happens if you use 'query user /server:servername' ?

Comment: 'query user /server:servername' resulted in the below message:..................Error 1722 getting sessionnames
Error [1722]:The RPC server is unavailable.

Comment: Hopeless, I did not try fully qualified name, i am trying with IP address. But with FQDN, the same error appears.

Comment: I'm having the same problem - six years later :)